# How to mark end of blockquote in markdown - react-markdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown, react-markdown

I've following markdown:

```
"Line0 

Line1

Line2

> 1
> 
> 2
> 
> 3
> 
> 4
> 
> 5
> 
> 6



line end"
```

I am using `react-markdown` to render this in UI. But `new lines` after then end of blockquotes are getting included in `blockquote`.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown

I tried several ways to make it work but none of the ways worked for me.

What I've tried:

1. Replacing /n with double space
2. Replacing /n with backslash \
3. Replacing /n with
4. Replacing /n with

No matter what I do, all the new lines after end of the blockquote are getting included in blockquote.

What I am getting:

[image]

HTML

[image]

Expected Output
[image]

Any help on this will be really appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the markdown string as in Markdown:

```
Line0\n\n\n\nLine1\n\n\n\n\n\nLine2\n\n> 1\n> \n> 2\n> \n> 3\n> \n> 4\n> \n> 5\n> \n> 6\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nline end\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n4\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n5
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid JavaScript string to me. Do you mean to use a template literal, with backticks? Please [edit] a syntactically valid input string into your question.

Comment: @Chris I've updated the question with Valid JS String. 

Sharing here as well: "Line0\n\n\n\nLine1\n\n\n\n\n\nLine2\n\n> 1\n> \n> 2\n> \n> 3\n> \n> 4\n> \n> 5\n> \n> 6\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nline end\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n4\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n5"

Comment: @Chris I made it work. Used this logic: replaced /\n\n(?=\n)/g  with '\n\n<span className="line-break"></span>' and CSS display: block;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;

Comment: Thanks @Chris for your valuable time :)

Answer (score 0):

Following changes worked for me:

```
const REG_EX = /\n\n(?=\n)/g;
const NEW_LINE_REPLACEMENT = '\n\n<span className="line-break"></span>';

transformedString = markdownString.replace(REG_EX, NEW_LINE_REPLACEMENT);


CSS
.line-break {
    display: block; 
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem; 
}
```